# Applications installed with brew cask install won't launch for other users

Tags: homebrew

I have two users accounts on my Mac, one for personal use and one for work use.  I use Homebrew to install most of my applications.

However, whatever GUI application I install using `brew cask install <app>`, it won't launch for the other user.  Every time I try to open such an app with the other user, I get an error like:

[image: The application "Spotify" can't be opened.]

I noticed that the application files are installed owned by the installer (in this case the user `work`):

```
$ ls -l /Applications/
 ...
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root    wheel   96 Feb 11 20:13 Siri.app/
drwxr-xr-x@  3 work    staff   96 Feb  6 19:52 Spotify.app/
```

How can I get the apps to launch also for other users on the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be some directories in the app folders missing the execute bit. You can check permissions using for example:

```
find /Applications/Spotify.app/ -type d -exec ls -ld {} \;
```

Directories should have permissions `drwxr-xr-x@` but some were `drwxr--r--@`.

The following command will change all directories to have the execute permission present:

```
sudo find /Applications/Spotify.app/ -type d -exec chmod og+x {} \;
```

The same needs to be run for all apps having this issue.